# Visual Studio 2015 Ionic template

Tags: ionic-framework, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-cordova

please I have Visual Studio 2015 Community and I also downloaded Ionic project template and I want start project with this template:
[image]

But I got this error message:
[image]

Please can you help me, what I am doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: Given how recent VS2015 is, I'd suggest trying this with VS2013. Its more than likely that this was the intended IDE for ionic

Comment: Don't use it, it is old and not using bower, make a blank cordova app and add bower ionic dependency, setup it yourself in vs 2015

Comment: Which Ionic template are you using? There are several available in the VS Extension Gallery, so it's hard to provide a recommendation. Also, which update of VS TACO are you using? The most recent in Update 8.1

Answer (score 0):

In the same window, you can see "Tools for Apache Cordova", above "Ionic Tabs App""

This is required for ionic projects to be recognized by Visual Studio. Click on it and then you'll get the option to download/install it.

Once it's done, restart Visual Studio and open your project.